# how is UICollectionView setting the readonly property of UICollectionViewLayout?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

while looking at UICollectionViewLayout, i noticed that its property UICollectionView is read-only

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UICollectionView *collectionView
```

> **Discussion**
>
> The collection view object sets the value of this property when a new layout object is assigned to it.

the collection view object mentioned here is UICollectionView instance.

how is UICollectionView setting a read-only property of a ***different class object*** (UICollectionViewLayout) here?

to be clear,

because this property is read-only, you can't do:

```
    UICollectionView *layout =...;
    layout.collectionView = someCollectionView; // compile error here since that property is read-only.
```

however, when you do

```
    [someCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    // this also updates layout.collectionView such that, 
    // layout.collectionView == someCollectionView
```

which basically means, inside this method, UICollectionView somehow successfully invoked

```
    layout.collectionView = someCollectionView;
```

how is it possible that collectionView modified the read-only property of layout object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [the class dump of `UICollectionViewLayout`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UICollectionViewLayout.h), you can see there is a private `- (void)_setCollectionView:(id)arg1` method which sets the collection view. So obviously, Apple has a setter which they use internally but **you are not meant to**. When you call `setCollectionViewLayout:`, internally Apple calls that setter method, as well as setup other properties necessary for their implementation to work.